# Can we have relevant icons on tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

Over on StackOverflow, some tags are decorated with relevant icons. For instance, [the tag for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) sports the Chrome icon, while [the Android tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) shows Bugdroid, the Android mascotte.

There is a great number of franchises that have a recognisable icon. *Star Trek* and *Star Wars* come to mind.

So can we decorate our tags with relevant icons, copyright permitting?

Comment: Ooh, nice idea!

Comment: Weren't the icons for tags some sort of sponsorship deal?

Comment: We are going to need sponsor for them. Related main meta question [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Comment: @AnkitSharma do we _need_ sponsorship deals for this?

Comment: @SQB I don't know if SE going to implement icon without sponsorship or not? And if they even accept more sponsorship or not. Only a CM can confirm that but i don't have any positive hope fro this implementation,

Comment: Do the SE take rep in exchange for sponsorship? I'm sure @Richard can sponsor a Buffy icon in a tag.